# Find if an ordinary differential equation is linear

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So my course shows me three differential equations:

$$\dot x + x^2 = t$$
$$\dot x = (t^2+1)(x-1)$$
$$\dot x + x = t^2$$

The first one is not a linear ordinary differential equation (ODE) apparently, the other two are.

Unfortunately, they don't show a clear way how to find out if an ODE is linear or not. So how we can find out if an ODE is linear?

For the second one, I thought I bring it into standard form somehow:

$$\dot x = (t^2+1)(x-1) = xt^2 + x - t^2 -1 = x(t^2+1)-t^2-1$$

If we say we let $p(t)=t^2+1$ and $q(t)=1+t^2$, then we could say:

$$\dot x = xp(t) - q(t) = ...$$

And so on, to simplify until we reach standard form of a linear ODE (or not).

Is that the way to go? Or is there some other way to check if a ODE is linear?

Comment: Starting on page 48 in (https://books.google.com/books?id=qxgcaAe_dHEC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=Linear%20Equations&f=false)[Arnol'd's ODE] is a section that explains how to recognize linear ODEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation) is a definition.   Accordingly,  the first is not linear, and the last two ode's are linear.  Note that we just need that the equation is a linear polynomial in $x$ and its derivatives.  That is, of the form: $a_{n+1}(t)x^{(n)}+\dots+a_1(t)x+a_0(t)=0$.  The functions $a_i(t)$ needn't be linear.

Comment: The equation $\dot x + x^2 = t$ is not linear by your definition,

Comment: @RobertLewis I see.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Glad to hep out  Cheers!